# Probability of having exactly 3 boys out of 5 babies if Pr(boys)=0.51

Tags: r, probability, multiplication

Assume 51% of all babies born are male, and all births are independent.  How would I calculate the probability of having exactly 3 boys (out of 5 babies) in R? I can solve arithmetically, but in R I haven't found a straightforward function.

Comment: *"How would I solve for having exactly 3 boys if I have 5 kids in R?"* Solve for what? What are you trying to calculate? The proportion of boys (i.e. `3/5`)?

Comment: Probability of having exactly 3 boys (3/5) if probability of having a boy is .51?

Comment: PS. Please note that questions asking us to recommend a package/tool/software are explicitly *off-topic* here on Stack Overflow. More fundamentally, it is much better to think about (R) coding in terms of "How can I achieve XYZ?" and "How do I implement XYZ programmatically?"  than "What package/function does XYZ".

Comment: Since you have an arithmetic solution, please provide those details in the main body of your post. That will help us understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: I don't usually downvote questions, but this was so poorly stated on a statsitical level, that I just couldn't hold back. The is no "addition/multiplication rule" that applies to this situation. I doubt that future users will find the question content useful in accessing the apparently useful answer given by Maurits Evers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dbinom(x, n, p)` gives the binomial probability mass function for `x` successes in `n` trials, given a probability of success `p`. Details are given if you type `?dbinom` in a terminal.

Provided I haven't misunderstood your question, in your case, the probability of seeing exactly 3 boys in 5 children, given a probability of 0.51 for having a boy, is then

```r
dbinom(3, 5, prob = 0.51)
#[1] 0.3184951
```

---

Or perhaps you're asking about the probability of observing ≥3 boys in 5 children?

```r
pbinom(2, 5, prob = 0.51, lower.tail = F)
#[1] 0.518745
```

(Note that the `2` here is not a typo/mistake, since `pbinom` with `lower.tail = F` gives Pr(X > x)).

---

Or the probability of seeing ≤3 boys in 5 children?

```r
pbinom(3, 5, prob = 0.51)
#[1] 0.7997501
```

---

### Update

We can compare the performance of *manually* calculating the binomial cumulative distribution using `sum` and `dbinom` with that of using `pbinom`

```
x <- 5000
n <- 10000
library(microbenchmark)
res <- microbenchmark(
    sum_mass = sum(dbinom(x:n, n, prob = 0.51)),
    cum_dist = pbinom(x - 1, n, prob = 0.51, lower.tail = F))
#Unit: microseconds
#     expr     min       lq      mean   median       uq      max neval
# sum_mass 736.276 773.8825 832.58220 797.3500 843.2485 1668.000   100
# cum_dist   2.136   2.7845   7.77986   4.0005   7.1765  252.872   100
```

Comment: `sum(dbinom(3:5, 5, prob = 0.51))` is more intuitive to me

Comment: @rawr Perhaps more intuitive from a pedagogical point of view but not necessarily advisable from a statistical/computational point-of-view, see my update:-)

Comment: Thanks Maurits. The dbinom() is exactly what I was looking for, and thank you for expanding upon it. My understanding of that function is/was off I think. It’s straightforward, but I was understanding it as calculating area under the curve that would get less precise the larger n gets. This beats writing out the factorials. Thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome @KurtRecker; I would really recommend rephrasing your original question to make it more precise (as suggested by @42-). That way you also help future readers identify relevant posts. At the moment, your post is "difficult" to understand.

Comment: @KurtRecker I have edited your post (and title) to be more descriptive and precise. Please take a look. Provided this answers your question, I recommend closing the question by setting the green check mark next to the answer.

Comment: That helps as an example as I get more active in these forums. Appreciate the help.

Comment: @KurtRecker Please close the question by setting the green check mark next to the answer. That way you help keeping SO tidy and make it easier for future readers to identify relevant questions. It's also SO's recommended way to say "thank you". Cheers and welcome to Stack Overflow:-)